# How to create a multirow table

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a multirow table in LaTeX which looks like the true positive, true negative, etc table shown in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29).

I am trying to use `multirow`, but I'm not sure how to get the y hat to be 'outside' the table.

```
\begin{table}[tbh!]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{$y$} \\ \hline
    %\multirow{3}{*}{$\hat{y}$} \\ 
    & \textbf{T} & \textbf{F} \\ \hline
    \textbf{T} & TP  & FP \\ \hline     
    \textbf{F} & FN & TN \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Truth and prediction comparison.}
\label{tab:revpol}
\end{table}
```

Can anyone explain what I need to change here to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to include the "out of table" components as part of the `tabular` structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|} 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$} \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \textbf{T} & \textbf{F} \\ \cline{2-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\hat{y}$} & \textbf{T} & TP  & FP \\ \cline{2-4}    
    & \textbf{F} & FN & TN \\ \cline{2-4}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Truth and prediction comparison.}
  \label{tab:revpol}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

`\cline`s are meant to put an `\hline` only in certain columns. `\multicolumn` is used to hide some of the vertical lines inserted using your `tabular` column specification.

On a side note, consider [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) as a `tabular` representation alternative.